# Closure compiler warning on for loop

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using a somewhat unconventional for loop that works well for what I'm doing as paraphrased below (not bothering to show variable declarations):

```
if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
    for (i = arr.length; i--; i) {
        element = arr.pop();
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

Closure compiler is giving me a warning of: "WARNING - Suspicious code.  This code lacks side effects, is there a bug?" Pointing specifically to the last "i" in the for loop parens.

If I remove the i, jslint throws a warning, if I leave it, closure throws a warning.  There are three of these loops in total, is there a "closure friendly" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How 'bout the normal way?

```
if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
    for (i = arr.length; i > 0; --i) {
        element = arr.pop();
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

Putting the decrement in the test is just not the normal way to write a `for` loop.

Or even more normal:

```
if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        element = arr.pop();
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

...but as you're not using `i`, it doesn't matter much.

Or you could use a `while`:

```
if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
    i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
        element = arr.pop();
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: I haven't. He's not using `i`, he's using `pop`.

Comment: You know... I can't remember why I was doing it that way, been a long day.  :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, if you're reducing an array's length, don't use a `for` loop, use a `while`:

```
if (arr) {
    while (arr.length) {
        element = arr.pop();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers... would never do this now... kind of embarrassing to see it up here

Answer (score 0):

Yeah--something like this should do the trick:

```
for (i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jshint rather jslint and turn off the warning.